# The component scope of n NgModule?

Tags: angular, typescript, scope, angular-components

I'll ask this question with an example.  We have this module:

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...
  import { TodoComponent } from './todo.component';
...

  @NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    exports: [TodosComponent, TodosFiltersComponent],
    declarations: [TodoComponent, TodosComponent, TodosFiltersComponent, TodosPageComponent]
  })
  export class TodosModule {}
```

I assume the `TodoComponent` and `TodoPageComponent` can only be used within the other declared components listed in the `declarations` array and these are the only components they can ever be used in, since they are not exported?  Just making sure I understand Angular component scope correctly ...

Comment: Yup, component of a module can only be used by components of the same module if there are not exported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use component in application you have to add it to declarations of any module.

To use component in other module than its base module you have to export this component.

Think about modules like "namespaces" for components.

Providers are totally different story.